# Is Ryan Clarke not a Phoenix?

Tags: character, legacies

In the episode 16th of "Legacies" (S01E16), Ryan Clarke (Landon's brother and Malivore's older child) was killed by Landon in the room of Malivore's pit. Now as Landon is a Phoenix, he catches fire before ressurection and leaves a lot of ash when he wakes up alive.

But when Ryan woke up, there was no fire or ash around. Is he not a Phoenix?

Answer (score 1):

The answer from the show is: We don't know what he is yet.

Malivore/Golem created him with his mud but he was infertile. We don't know which species it is but it's some imperfect species with immortality as he can rise after being killed.

So we have to either wait for the second season for that answer or some official interview.

Wikia calls him [Golem](https://vampirediaries.fandom.com/wiki/Ryan_Clarke) but it was not explicitly mentioned in the show and he doesn't seem to have powers like his father. Also, Landon Kirby took birth from a women but Ryan was made with the mud out of Golem.